# How can I create nice-looking, functional overlays like what's being used in SharePoint 2010 in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, model-view-controller

I have tried in my MVC app to add jquery modal dialogs to prompt the user for input, but my code turned really sloppy just prompting the user for 1 field of information.

SharePoint 2010 has ajax overlays that are very functional, some even include the office ribbon.

How is this being done?  What libraries can I use where I can open up entire forms as ajax overlays on top of a page?

Thanks so much!

Comment: SharePoint 2010 uses div's with iframes. You can use http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog and put an iframe inside the dialog div. There are also other jquery plugins which handles this like http://chriswanstrath.com/facebox/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show complete forms, use http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-framedialog - I haven't tried it with standard SharePoint forms, but it should work if you set the return url to a page that will close the dialog.

If you just need a nicer looking javascript prompt, use the standard jQuery UI dialog and define the html for the form where you are using it.

With MVC you may find it easiest to post the form using ajax (there is a jquery method to serialize a form, though I don't recall the exact syntax) rather than posting the iframe - that gets you a callback structure that is a bit easier to work with if you are doing more complex stuff with the dialogs.